# How to set selectd values in kendo multiselect dropdown

Tags: visual-studio, kendo-ui

I am having a kendo multiselect dropdown in a window dialog, and i wanted to show already selected values as default values on the kendo multi select dropdown.
How can i do that?

Comment: Check out the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/multiselect/overview#multiselect-overview) from Telerik on Multiselect. Check out their [example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index) as well.

Comment: @Supersnake, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataSource: [
        { Name: "Item1", Id: 1 },
        { Name: "Item2", Id: 2 },
        { Name: "Item3", Id: 3 },
        { Name: "Item4", Id: 4 }
    ],
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id"
});

$("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect").value([2, 3]);
```